# Will the Stepper Motor 17HS3401 work fine with the TMC2130 driver? Or is the driver chip going to burn? Are they compatible?

Tags: stepper-motor, mosfet-driver, stepper-driver, motordriver

I am considering whether to buy the stepper motor 17HS3401 of [this catalog](http://datasheetcafe.databank.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/17HS4401.pdf)

[image]

### Current

The motor uses a rated current of 1.3A. I need to connect it to the [TMC2130 driver](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet.pdf), which accepts just 1.2A with some peak of 2.5A. Should I be worried? Is the motor going to burn the diver chip in the long term?

### Voltage

Also, the voltage is not shown in the motor features. Should I multiply the "Rated Current (A)" and the "Phase Resistance(ohm)" to get the voltage? >> `1.3A x 2.4ohm = 3.12V`. It seems very low to me because most of this kind of motors use 12V or even 24V. Are my calculations right?

Comment: There are a LOT of posts about this that would answer your question. The stepper driver will drive the motor with a constant current (that you set), the drive current/voltage are not given by the resistance of the winding.

Comment: @WesleyLee so, how can I calculate the voltage I need to make the motor work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher operating voltages translate to higher stepping rates (and higher peak RPM, higher torque at higher RPMs).  If you operate the motor from 3.12V, you will get the rated torque at 0 RPM (aka holding force), but performance at any speed will be poor.  Since the TMC2130 driver is a constant current PWM driver, higher voltages (up to the rated voltage of the TMS2130 and any filter caps/etc) will produce better motor performance.  The TMS2130 chip may get hotter (due to the internal LDO to drive internal circuitry).

For most applications you will be fine with 12V.

Additional simplified explanation:  The higher voltages are needed to quickly change the current flow in the motor coils